# AudioPlayer seek option doesn't move to the right position

Tags: flutter, audio-player, seek

I'm using AudioPlayer in flutter to play local audio files.
I have an issue with seek option.

when I use a position like 1000ms,2000ms,3000ms ...... it works
but when I use positions like 1200ms or 2750ms it round it down

for example if i use any value from 1000 to 1999 ms it will all be round down to 1000ms and the seek option will position to 1000ms

same thing if i use any value from x000 to x999 ms it will all be round down to x000ms

any advise please

regards

Cherif

Comment: Can you show the code for your Slider widget?